# how to use SUM query in laravel?

Tags: laravel, sum

I want to run this query, where multiple values are separated by "COMMA" using Laravel

```
SELECT SUM(LENGTH(textfield) - LENGTH(REPLACE(textfield, ',', '')) + 1)
FROM tablename
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#raw-methods

Answer (score 0):

```
    $sum = DB::table('tablename')
        ->selectRaw("SUM(LENGTH(textfield) - LENGTH(REPLACE(textfield, ',', ''))) + 1 ")
        ->get();


    return $sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DB::raw in query for any kind of calculation.

```
$sum = DB::table('tablename')
                ->select(DB::raw("SUM(LENGTH(textfield) - LENGTH(REPLACE(textfield, ',', ''))) + 1 "))
                ->get();
       return $sum;
```